# Given # of rows and columns and dimensions of kernal can you find a b such that no solutions exist

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for a step in the right direction on how to approach this problem. I know that the equation (I) is in the form for finding the kernal (nullspace). The fact that the two sample solutions are linearly independent and span the space indicate they make up the basis of the kernal. Therefore, the dimension of the kernal must be 2. We know the # of columns as 27 therefore the dimension of the image (rank of matrix) must be 27-2 = 25.

I know for no solutions to exist it must be inconsistent such that after row reduced echoleon form the equation (II) must have a row of zeros but on the right side have a number that is non-zero.

This is where I am drawing a blank on how to approach the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints. All use the rank-nullity theorem.

a) In matrix form, the nullspace is 2-dimensional, so the column space is 27 dimensional. That means every vector in $\mathbb {R}^m$ is a linear combination.

b) The nullspace is still 2-dimensional, so the column space is 26 dimensional and sits in a dimension 27 space.

c) The column space has dimension 76, so what is the dimension of the nullspace?

Comment: I see where I made a major mistake and was thinking n x m matrix but its m x n. Thanks a lot for the hints